# How to PARTITION BY two columns when using FIRST_VALUE()

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

| Region | Item | Units_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asia | pen | 1000 |
| asia | book | 5432 |
| asia | milk | 8899 |
| north_america | pen | 87 |
| north_america | book | 342 |
| north_america | milk | 8374 |

Above is a view I created and I'm trying to select the region and item only of the highest unist_sold row. I tried using first_value function but I can't partition by two columns.

```
SELECT distinct 
        region, FIRST_VALUE(units_sold)
        OVER (PARTITION BY region
                ORDER BY units_sold DESC
                RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED 
                  FOLLOWING)
    AS BEST_SELLING
FROM region_view
ORDER BY region;
```

This gives me only the region and its corresponding highest units_sold. But I need to have the corresponding item as well.

Below is the expected outcome. Thank you.

| Region | Item | Units_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asia | milk | 8899 |
| north_america | milk | 8374 |

Comment: "I can't partition by two columns" - why? Please, post your code and an error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is really a candidate for `ROW_NUMBER` rather than `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY Units_sold DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT Region, Item, Units_sold
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```